# How Does LabVIEW Handle Multiprocessing and Multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, labview

**INTRO**

**multiprocessing** = using multiple CPU cores to complete a task (each core has separate memory, thus requires pipes and data structures for each core to "talk" to each other")

**multithreading** = using multiple threads (that are on a single CPU core) with a task scheduler to complete a task (all threads share same memory on CPU core)

- **static (temporal) multithreading** - take advantage of idle I/O time by scheduling tasks to occur sequentially without pause during cache misses (i.e. waiting to read/write to an I/O device); used for I/O-bound tasks
- **dynamic (simultaneous) multithreading** - take advantage of instructions that can happen at the same time (on Intel chips, this is called "Hyperthreading"); used for CPU-bound tasks

  - e.g.

```
a = b*c //Task 1
d = e*f //Task 2
g = a*d //Task 3

// Task 1 and 2 don't depend on each other, and hence can be run in parallel
```

**QUESTION**

Given the above, how can I control in LabVIEW which cores I use to multiprocess a task (not multithread)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of NI LabVIEW version 8.5 the **Timed Loop** and **Timed Sequence** structures include a **Processor** input that allows you to manually assign available processors to handle the execution of the structures. You can configure the processor assignment by wiring an input to the Processor input of the Input Node for the structure or for frames of the structure.

http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/6400/en/

Answer (score 3):

LabVIEW inherently parses the dataflow out to multiple processors and multiple threads to as much parallelism as the system is analyzed to stand. THERE ARE ALMOST ZERO CASES WHERE YOU SHOULD SPECIFY THE THREADING MODEL OF THE CODE. The Timed Loop and Timed Structure capabilities should be considered strictly for real-time systems, not for execution on the desktop systems (Windows, Mac, or Linux). If you attempt to specify the threading model, you will almost certainly get less performance than the sophisticated model already computed by the compiler and run-time engine.

Comment: Though, that's theory. In reality, LV sticks pretty much to one CPU.

Comment: @sweber As do most apps, because crossing CPU is less efficient. It is avoided when possible.

Comment: Yes, though LV is a programming language and should allow parallel programming. We have a quite big project, separated into several tasks. They communicate via queues, which makes it perfect for multi-CPU machines. However, it sticks to just one.

Comment: My apps span onto multiple CPUs all the time.